# QGIS "delete identical" points?

Tags: qgis, point

Using QGIS, I have two layers of points where most of the points are overlaying each other.I want to delete the points of the first layer that are overlaying with the points of the second layer and keep the ones that stand alone.

In ArcGIS, this tool is called "delete identical", where I have one input layer and one layer that is compared to that input.
Do you know something similar in QGIS? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the Difference tool (as suggested by EricLohmann) should work. Since it didn't, here's another method to try.

**Step 1: Use the Spatial Query tool to select overlapping points.**

Find the Spatial Query tool in the Vector Menu. You may need to enable it from the Plugin menu > Manage and install plugins.

Use the Spatial Query tool to select source features from the first layer where the feature equals reference features of the second layer.

[image]

*If all the identical features are selected, proceed to step 3.* If not, it may be because the points are very close together but not identical.

**Step 2: Buffer the second layer and repeat the spatial query using the buffer layer.**

Vector menu > geoprocessing > fixed distance buffer
Choose a buffer distance small enough that the closest non-identical points will not fall within each others buffers. My closest non-identical points are 0.006 degrees apart, so I used a buffer of 0.001 degrees.

[image]

*Repeat step 1, using the first points layer and the new buffer layer.*

**Step 3: Delete the selected points from the first point layer.**
Turn on editing for the layer. Use the Delete selected button. Save edits.

[image]

Comment: Or use Select by location tool from Vector menu > research tools. This is pretty much the same as the Spatial Query tool.

Comment: Did you have to make a buffer, or did spatial query work for you with the points layers?

Answer (score 1):

"Difference" is your best friend in this situation. The first layer is layer one, the second layer is your difference layer, run it, and hopefully you are happy. If not, your features do not exactly overlap.

Comment: Thank you, but this way I only get a table as output data, not a layer/ shapefile..

Comment: In that case I dare to say that something went wrong, be it due to your data, or due to some error in QGis.